# Dates are coming back invalid using openNTF jdbc driver for Domino

Tags: database, sqlite, jdbc, lotus-domino

I'm creating reports utilizing openNTF's domSQL/JDBC driver for Domino (powered by SQLite).  It enables us to use Domino's databases as SQL database views.  One of the features of this driver is that it converts all the Domino db date fields to text fields.  Somehow, in doing this, it sometimes converts the date 'xxxx-02-28 xx:xx:xx' to 'xxxx-02-29 xx:xx:xx'. Not only is the date incorrect, but 2/29 is a leapyear date being assigned to non-leapyears. This is causing an additional error when we attempt to store this invalid date into a date field.

More info on DomSQL can be found [here](http://www.openntf.org/Projects/pmt.nsf/302F81BB4D8401E78625797B00293AF5/$file/DominoJDBCAccess.pdf)

Comment: and yes, I've tried converting it to a date type. still no luck.

Comment: Seems like you should be filing a defect on the project's page on OpenNTF, although admittedly I don't know if anyone is supporting that project any more. Kind of doubtful since the author no longer works for IBM, but you never know. Have you looked at the source? I just did, and I see date-related functions in both the Java and C++ portions, but nothing obvious jumps out at me.

Comment: Well that's comforting lol...I hope there's at least some level of support for it.  I haven't picked at the source yet.  I thought I'd see if anyone else was familiar with it first.

Comment: On closer look, the project on OpenNTF has multiple authors. The dev that I know left IBM may not have even been the principal developer, though he does seem to have been the most active person answering questions in the project discussion. At least two of the project owners do have profiles here on StackOverflow, so maybe one of them will take notice, but I'd still post the bug on OpenNTF though.

Comment: OpenNTF issue opened [here](https://github.com/OpenNTF/DomSQL/issues/3)

Answer (score 0):

We installed a hotfix for Domino that solved this issue.  The hotfix was:

HF 391 for 9.0.1FP2